# ActiveAdmin meta search filters - filter by association id select dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, meta-search

I have a model setup like this:

- `Sale` belongs to `Product`
- `Product` belongs to `Varietal`

Now I want to make a select drop down filter for varietal on sales.  The only way I've managed to do this is by name.

```
filter :product_varietal_name,
  as: :select,
  label: 'Varietal name',
  collection: Varietal.names_for_select
```

But I want to be able to serach by `varietal_id` since I have an index on that column, it should be much faster. I seem to be unable to do so, however.

```
filter :product_varietal       # undefined method `product_varietal_eq'
filter :product_varietal_id    # undefined method `product_varietal_eq'
filter :product_varietal_id_eq # undefined method `product_varietal_id_eq_eq'
filter :product_varietal_eq    # undefined method `product_varietal_eq_eq'
```

There is clearly some magic here around the `_id` at the end of the filter name.  And this magic is not doing what I want.

The only case this *does* work is when the association is on the Model being viewed.  So `Sale` belongs to `Product`, and `filter :product` works as you would expect.

So how can I make a drop down select box filter that searches on `sale.product.varietal_id`?

Comment: Since it works on a direct association you could try `has_one :varietal, through: :product` inside `Sale` and then `filter :varietal`

Comment: @mdesantis That might work, but I'd rather not change the data model just to make this searchable.  I'm sure search can do what I want, I'm just not finding the right magic syntax.

Comment: I'd suggest trying the latest code on GitHub to see if `filter :product_varietal_id` works there